# Connecting to my own Hyperledger Fabric instance

Tags: ibp-vscode-extension

I am new to IBM Blockchain Platform VSCode Extension and using IBM Blockchain Platform Extension Version: 0.3.2 and Visual Studio Code version: 1.32.3.

In this extension there is a feature "Connecting to your own Hyperledger Fabric instance". I tried this by using the command "Add Gateway" in VSCode. I have provided connection profile, cert and private key. It successfully connected and showing only channel name under "FABRIC GATEWAYS". No peers are showing. But now my question is, how to install and initiate smart contract using the extension? Nothing is showing under "LOCAL FABRIC OPS" which was showing when I connect to pre-configured local fabric instance. Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to install chaincode or instantiate chaincode on an external network (ie one that isn't managed by the vscode plugin itself), although as you have already discovered you can connect a gateway to it to test your running chaincode. So you can perform an install/instantiate on your external network then use the plugin to interact with it.
If the network provided by the plugin isn't suitable for you to use for your local testing then I would suggest raising an issue at
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues
describing why the in built network isn't suitable and what sort of inbuilt network would be suitable.